# CSS: get color from angular

Tags: jquery, angular

From jquery we can take the color from an element like this

```
$('#js-color-profile').find('.color-primary-50').css('color')
```

in angular 2+ is any workaround to get the hex color?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it with vanilla js like this. The getPropertyValue is not necessary, but the getComputedStyle will return all css for the element, that's why I wrote it there.

```
getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('color')
```

or

```
getComputedStyle(element, null)['color']
```